# Need of Client in API

Tags: python, api, rest

> Why do we need a client for API calls ? What is client and it's use ?
> The question may not be great but it is really confusing as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Client is simply the party that calls an api -which exist on the server side-. Some languages require you to create a pre-defined client object to post your requests, but you are always the client when you send a request.

Answer (score 0):

An API is like a shop. It has lots of things to look at and sometimes buy. A client is a customer. The customer can browse the things in the shop and perhaps buy something.

You can have a shop without customers, which is the same as an API no-one knows about. If the shop owner distributes business cards with details on how to come into the shop, look around and buy, then customers can use the shop.

The business card is like the API description ([swagger](https://swagger.io/) etc), allowing clients to connect to the API and use it.

Customers can get the bus to the shop and look for stuff, this is like using [REST](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest) code you develop yourself to use an API. Or the shop owner can arrange to pick up a customer from their home, transport them to the shop and give them a brochure of what is inside. This is like a custom developed client app (in C#, Java, Ruby, whatever) for the API.

Using REST code might look like:

```
    response = requests.get("https://shop.com/api/book?title="API 101");
    # parse response to a book object
```

a custom developed client might look like:

```
Book = BookShopClient.getBookByTitle("API 101");
```